# How to prevent an Ajax form from submitting

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, webforms

The below code blocks any non-ajax form from submitting.

```
$(this.form)
  .on('submit', function(event) {
    if (/* Some condition */) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

In Drupal 8, how can we block an Ajax form from being submitted?

Ajax forms do not trigger a form submit handler and I have not been able to block the click event on an Ajaxified form's submit buttons.

For reference, I am trying to fix [Issue #3010084: Form submission finishes before file upload is complete](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3010084)

Answer (score 16):

I found the solution [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation/issues/2952233).

```
// Add submit handler to form.beforeSend.
// Update Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend only once.
if (typeof Drupal.Ajax !== 'undefined' && typeof Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSubmitOriginal === 'undefined') {
  Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSubmitOriginal = Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSubmit;
  Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element_settings, options) {
    if (/* Custom condition */) {
      this.ajaxing = false;
      return false;
    }
    return this.beforeSubmitOriginal();
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on your solution ? How do you implement this code ? I know php and JS but I don't know how AJAX is working in Drupal since I do mostly integration and theming.

Comment: I've used this code in my projet and it didn't work. Then, I've copied the code from your patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-19/2952233-5.patch and it works. But I'm still interested in an explanation because I'm not sure to understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing a form submit while the form ajax handler is ongoing

```
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('#edit-next').removeAttr("disabled");
  });

  /**
   * prevent submit in case of ongoing ajax update
   */
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#edit-next").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } );
```