# How to remove the click event on an Ajaxified form's submit buttons?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've created several forms with Drupal 8 directly in admin or with Form API. I've added some client side validation with this jQuery plugin : [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org).

Everything works very well. Now my client asked me to open one of these form in a popin. So I've installed this 2 modules : 
Contact Block (The Contact Block module provides contact forms in a block.) https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_block

I can open form in a popin and it works well but after validation, the page is reloaded and it is not UX friendly since we are in a popin.
So I've installed this module : 
Contact ajax (implements ajax submission for core Contact form in Drupal 8.) https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_ajax

It works well but the submission is done before I can execute client side validation.

The problem seems to be the priority of execution.

I've tried to apply `preventDefault` on the submit button but it doesn't work.

```
$( "#form #submit-button" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //validation code
});
```

I've found this topic but I donc know how to implement the code :
[How to prevent an Ajax form from submitting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271808/how-to-prevent-an-ajax-form-from-submitting/271815#271815)

I've also found this topic :
https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation

Can you help me to understand how I can  block the click event on an Ajaxified form's submit buttons ?

**EDIT**

I've tried this module : [Clientside Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) and apply this patch [2952233-5.patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation/issues/2952233)

It works, the Ajax submit button is disabled. The solution is based on that [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271808/how-to-prevent-an-ajax-form-from-submitting/271815#answer-271815).

For now it has a bug : the form is validated but I don't see the confirmation message at the end.

Then, I've copied the code from this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-19/2952233-5.patch)  in my project and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $( "#form #submit-button" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
};
```

Can you try like this. This will trigger for every AJAX call.

Comment: Could you expand on your solution ? How do you implement this code ? I know php and JS but never used `Drupal.behaviors`

Comment: This code is similar to $(document).ready().If we write anything inside Drupal. behaviors, it will trigger for every ajax click.https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview read this documentation

Comment: I've added this code in the js custom file but the submit button is still Ajaxified. Also, I've edited my question.